# How to differentiate between node click and hyperlink text click on element in jointjs

Tags: jointjs

```
var el1 = new joint.shapes.custom.ElementLink({    
position: { x: 80, y: 80 },    
size: { width: 170, height: 100 },    
attrs: {    
rect: { fill: '#E67E22', stroke: '#D35400', 'stroke-width': 5 },    
a: { 'xlink:href': 'http://jointjs.com', 'xlink:show': 'new', cursor: 'pointer' },    
text: { text: 'Element as a link:\nhttp://jointjs.com', fill: 'white' }    

}

});
```

I want a handler for anchor tag where I can call any event from my viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want exactly. If you're using the `joint.shapes.custom.ElementLink` from this tutorial: http://jointjs.com/tutorial/hyperlinks, then this shape is defined so that it is totally wrapped in the `<a>` anchor tag and so clicking anywhere inside the element will follow the link. However, you can catch the click event and, for example, based on the target of the event or some other condition decide whether you want to follow the link or do other things:

```
paper.on('cell:pointerclick', function(cellView, evt, x, y) {
    // evt.target contains the SVG subelement that was the target of the click
    // cellView is the view for the joint.shapes.custom.ElementLink cell model
    // cellView.model is the cell model
    if (someCondition) {
        // This is how you can prevent the default browser action which is
        // following the <a> link.
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
})
```